# Capture Tortoise SVN folder info (not just the URL)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to perform an audit of client environment information that we have stored in Tortoise SVN.  There are 300+ such folders.  I'm trying to capture info and copy/paste it into an Excel spreadsheet.

The problem: I select all the folders and do a Ctrl+C to copy.  However, it ONLY captures the URLs (as in performing the "Copy URL to clipboard" function).  I ALSO want to capture dates and times.

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this?  I am NOT about to manually type 300+ dates into my spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Copy what from where?

Comment: I'm just trying to copy folder information (basically exactly the same as the "Copy URL to clipboard" function). -- except I want more than the URL.  I also want the date/time (and maybe other meta) information.  I need to get this for 300+ folders.

Comment: Alright, you probably refer to the TortoiseSVN context menu in Windows Explorer. A GUI tool is normally not appropriate for automation. You may want to use the command line client (which, BTW, comes as optional component in TortoiseSVN package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with SVN commands today, and discovered that the following command gave me exactly what I wanted:

```
svn list -v [name of repo source folder]
```